# SQLite Create View to Display Table Columns in Rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, view

Let's say I have a Table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_TableFullOfStuff (id INTEGER, Name STRING,
    date1 INTEGER, date2 INTEGER);
```

With Stuff in it:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_TableFullOfStuff VALUES(1,"thing one", 1448486601, 1448486602);
INSERT INTO tbl_TableFullOfStuff VALUES(2,"thing two", 1448486605, 1448486606);
INSERT INTO tbl_TableFullOfStuff VALUES(3,"thing three", 1448486603, 1448486604);
```

How can I create a view that makes an independent row for each timestamp?

```
NAME        |TIMESTAMP
thing one   |1448486601
thing one   |1448486602
thing three |1448486603
thing three |1448486604
thing two   |1448486605
thing two   |1448486606
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS
SELECT name, date1 AS TIMESTAMP
FROM tbl_TableFullOfStuff
UNION ALL
SELECT name, date2 AS TIMESTAMP
FROM tbl_TableFullOfStuff;

SELECT *
FROM my_view
ORDER BY name, TIMESTAMP;
```

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/199de/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: AMAZING! Thanks for the assist.